# How to add Google play services to my virtual device?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm setting up Android environment for my android app. When I click on Login with the Google on my app's login screen it says

> play services not available or outdated

This is my first time setting this up and a step by step guide will be helpful.

Comment: Use an image with google play services when creating the virtual device.

Comment: @Henry See the problem is I'm not understanding where to start from and what options to chose. That's why I said step by step guide is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use an image with google play services when creating the virtual device.
Here is screenshot for clear understanding.
[image]